# How do I add a background image to a GTK TreeView?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

I would like to to have a GTK TreeView with a background image as shown in the mockup below.

I have found methods for setting the background *color* of widgets, but there does not appear to be a method for setting a background `pixbuf` or other image format.

I'm using Python with PyGTK but an answer in any language with GTK bindings is acceptable.

**Mockup of gtkTreeView with background image**:

[image: Mockup of GTK TreeView with background image]

**First Attempt**

Based on Jong Bor's advice, I tried the following:

```
style = treeview.get_style().copy()
img_pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(image_filename)
img_pixmap = img_pixbuf.render_pixmap_and_mask()[0]
for state in (gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.STATE_ACTIVE, gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT,
              gtk.STATE_SELECTED, gtk.STATE_INSENSITIVE):
    style.bg_pixmap[state] = img_pixmap
treeview.set_style(style)
```

At first this didn't seem to have any effect, but upon selecting an item in my `TreeView` I observed the following:

[image: Selected row showing part of the background image]

Part of the background 'shows through' when a row is selected.

(Note that I'm using a background image based on my mockup, except that it has some blue color, for test purposes).

I then activated part of my GUI that clears the contents of the TreeView and redraws it, and observed this:

[image: Tiled background visible]

However as soon as I add something to the TreeView the background disappears, so I'm still not sure if this is going in the right direction.

Comment: Does calling treeview.show_all() after populating the treeview make the background visible? Also, a hackish suggestion: since selecting a row makes the background visible, do something like treeview.get_selection().select_all() to select all rows.

Comment: @Jong show_all() doesn't seem to have an effect. Also, select_all() wouldn't work to show the background unless the entire TreeView is full, and even then the interface would no longer work for the user. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that since each cell has a renderer which controls its appearance, you would have to somehow modify the treeview cell by cell.

Anyway, the following code might be worth a try (untested, incomplete code):

```
# Get the treeview's style
style = treeview.get_style().copy()

# Change the bg_pixmap attribute
#   It's an array with one pixbuf for every widget state, so
#   you probably want to replace each of the default 
#   pixmap's with your own image(s)
#   

style.bg_pixmap[0] = your_pixmap
style.bg_pixmap[1] = your_pixmap
style.bg_pixmap[2] = your_pixmap
style.bg_pixmap[3] = your_pixmap
style.bg_pixmap[4] = your_pixmap

# Set the modified style
treeview.set_style(style)
```

The bg_pixmap attribute is documented in the [PyGTK reference](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkstyle.html).

I'm not sure of how the array positions map to widget states. If it is the same as in c++, it will be:

```
0 - STATE_NORMAL    
1 - STATE_ACTIVE    
2 - STATE_PRELIGHT  
3 - STATE_SELECTED  
4 - STATE_INSENSITIVE
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I tried this method and it does not have any noticeable effect. I also tried setting the `bg_pixmap` values directly (instead of copying the style first and the setting it back on the widget) and it did not work either. I think the `bg_pixmap` only affects parts of the widget where window background is visible, but the `TreeView` widget covers the window background with its white fill.

Comment: Kind of expected that. I edited the answer before seeing your comment to suggest that it was a long shot indeed. Since every cell has a renderer which allows changing its appearance, a brute force approach would be to modify every cell's background. Unless someone with deeper knowledge on the inner workings of Gtk can shed some light on the problem...

Comment: On further investigation, I've found that setting the bg_pixmap attribute does have some effect. I set each value in the bg_pixmap array to the pixmap of my image and it causes the selection color of the a selected row to be part of my image. Sometimes the image will even show up tiled as the background, but only when the TreeView is empty. I'll add a screenshot to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Using GTK3 and gtkmm it is possible to use CSS, but the image needs to available as a file or possibly a resources.

Here I assume that the treeview is subclassed:

```
class MyTreeView : public Gtk::TreeView { .. };
```

for you treeview set a name and then add a CSS style to it:

```
MyTreeView::MyTreeView () {

  set_name ("MyTreeView");
  auto css = Gtk::CssProvider::create ();
  auto sc  = get_style_context ();

  string path_to_img = "my-image.png";

  string css_data =
    ustring::compose (
                    "#MyTreeView  { background-image: url(\"%1\");"
                    "               background-repeat: no-repeat;"
                    "               background-position: 50%% 50%%;"
                    " }\n"
                    "#MyTreeView  .hide_bg { background-image: none; }",
                    path_to_img);

  try {
    css->load_from_data (css_data);
  } catch (Gtk::CssProviderError &e) {
    cout "error: attempted to set background image: " << path_to_img.c_str () << ": " << e.what () << endl;
  }

  auto screen = Gdk::Screen::get_default ();
  sc->add_provider_for_screen (screen, css, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

}
```

it seems that it is also possible to set the background of the *row* to transparent by adding:

```
background: none;
```

to the CSS.

The background image can then be hidden or shown using:

```
if (!hide) {
  auto sc = get_style_context ();
  if (!sc->has_class ("hide_bg")) sc->add_class ("hide_bg");
} else {
  auto sc = get_style_context ();
  if (sc->has_class ("hide_bg")) sc->remove_class ("hide_bg");
}
```

[image]